# Using 'Ibid' within footnoting A Level

Tags: poetry, citation, reference

I am currently completing my final piece of A Level coursework for English Literature.

I have cited a quote, and then the second quote is from a different place. Wrote out all the relevant details for the two sources. Simple.

**BUT THEN**, my following (third) quote is from the same place as the first, so do I have to write the book title out all over again because its not following straight after, or can I use 'Ibid'? If so, how?

Comment: Hi. Are you saying you're putting the full citation in the footnote, rather than a reference to the bibliography? Also, did your teacher hand out a style guide?

Comment: 1. Figure out what style you should be using—I thought "Harvard" style was most common for A levels, which is an author-date style that wouldn't need footnotes or *ibid*, but I'm not British. 2. Find a style guide for your particular style, to see what it says, or if you can't find one add more info to your question here. 3. If it's allowed at your school, start using a citation manager—it will make your life so much easier now and if you ever do research on the future! I'm most familiar with Zotero and RefWorks, but there are many out there. Imagine never typing out a reference again...

Comment: You certainly can't use *ibid* in that situation. It used to be that if you used *ibid* to indicate the same reference as one that was given immediately prior, *op. cit.* was used to indicate the same reference—but when it was out of sequence. Using *op. cit.* would require providing the author's name too. But it's fallen out of favour, since it can be awkward reading back up the reference list to locate the reference. Most modern style guides and systems of citation use different methods.